# ASP.NET Core - embedded resource (Microsoft Identity) is not found when environment is Stage. It works fine when it is Development

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor, environment, staging

I have a ASP.NET Core Blazor Server with Identity. When I run in the Development environment, everything works as expected. Specifically, the embedded css and js files are loaded. Example: "~/Identity/css/site.css", "~/Identity/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js".
But when I change the environment to Staging, all the files in "~/Identity/..." path are not found, returning 404 error. And it is not just my project. I created a brand new scaffolded Blazor app with Identity, and it behaves exactly the same. Any ideas why? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/index.html.

ZhiLv-MSFT answered · 6 hours ago
Hi @panpawel-3022,

The static web assets are enabled by default in the Development environment. To support assets in other environments when running from build output, call UseStaticWebAssets on the host builder in Program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets();
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Reference: [Consume content from a referenced RCL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)